# ¿Por qué no se envía a mi base de datos mi formulario?

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios

Tras solucionar el error de subir archivos a un determinado fichero, me doy cuenta de que no me da ningún error de php, pero que tampoco recibe mi base de datos mysqli ningún dato, he probado con var_dump y si se envían mediante POST los datos, pero por alguna razón mi base de datos no los almacena. Dejo aquí mis code:

HTML FORM CODE:

```
 <div class="formulario">
    <span class="recuerde">   <i class="fas fa-lock"></i> Recuerde que toda su información se encuentra encriptada.      </span>
    <form class="postulacion" method="POST" action="assets/php/send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form_nombre">
            <label for="nombre">
                ¿Cuál es su nombre? Ponga únicamente su primer nombre.
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,15}" maxlength="20" title="Introduzca un nombre correcto." required />
        </div>
        <div class="form_apellido">
            <label for="apellido">
                ¿Cuál es su apellido? <span class="info_apellido">Ponga solo su primer apellido</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,15}" maxlength="20" title="Introduzca un apellido correcto." required />
        </div>
        <div class="form_email">
            <label for="email">
                ¿Cuál es su e-mail? <span class="info_email">Solo lo usaremos para enviarte actualizaciones sobre tu postulación. </span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" title="Introduzca un email correcto." maxlength="30" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form_movil">
            <label for="numero">
                ¿Cuál es su número de teléfono? <span class="info_numero">Lo necesitaremos para ponernos en contacto contigo. </span>
            </label>
            <input type="number" name="movil" pattern="[0-9]{9}" maxlength="12" title="Introduzca un número de teléfono correcto, sin el +34" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form_puesto">
            <label for="puesto">
                ¿Para qué puesto aspiras?
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="puesto" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" maxlength="20" title="Introduzca un puesto de trabajo correcto." required />
        </div>
        <div class="form_cv">
            <label for="cv">
                Suba su curriculum
            </label>
            <input type="file" name="vandal" value="Adjuntar" title="Adjunte un archivo." size="150" maxlength="150" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form_salario">
            <label for="salario">
                ¿Deseas recibir el salario por adelantado?
            </label>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="Sí" title="Seleccione una opción." required />
            <label for="seleccion">Sí</label>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="No" title="Seleccione una opción." required />
            <label for="seleccion">No</label>
        </div>


        <button class="form_send" type="submit" name="submit">Enviar Formulario</button>


    </form>
```

PHP SEND.PHP CODE:

```
<?php
include 'data.php'; //file which contains db config.
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['vandal']['tmp_name'])) { 
     
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$movil = $_POST['movil'];
$puesto = $_POST['puesto'];
$seleccion = $_POST['seleccion'];// En los casos de radio inputs, tenemos que asignarle un mismo "name" a los dos, para que funcione de forma correcta. 
                              // Quedaría algo así: Seleccion = no, o Seleccion = si.


$query = "INSERT INTO register(email, nombre, apellido, movil, puesto,  seleccion) VALUES('$email','$nombre','$seleccion','$movil','$puesto','$apellido')";




     
      // creamos las variables para subir a la db
        $ruta = "../../data-gathered/files"; 
        $nombrefinal= trim ($_FILES['vandal']['name']); //Eliminamos los espacios en blanco
        $nombrefinal= str_replace(" ", "", $nombrefinal);
        $upload= $ruta . '/' . $nombrefinal;  



        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['vandal']['tmp_name'], $upload)) { //movemos el archivo a su ubicacion 
                   
                    echo <<<EOT
                    
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/completed.css">
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./assets/img/favicon.ico">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=../../success/index.php">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                   <div class="root">
                   </div>
                   </body>
                   </html>

                   
                    
          EOT;         
                   
                    
                    }

}
}
 else {
    print 'xd';
}
```

Code db connect:

```
<?php

$seckey='1111';  // Here is the admin-access key

$servername = "127.0.0.1";  // Host
$username = "root";  //User
$password = ''; // Password
$dbname = "registro"; // dbname

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$connp = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);


?>
```

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$_FILES['vandal']['error']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La variable `$query` es la orden que se le va a mandar a la base de datos, la cuál se tiene que mandar con:

```
$conn -> query($query);
```

O con:

```
$insert = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

La función `query` manda la orden a la base de datos.
Que no se te olvide añadir:

```
require 'file.php' //file es el nombre que le hayas puesta al archivo con la variable $conn
```